# Find the Length of Angle Bisector of a Triangle Given SAS

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

The question is a follows:

> The lengths of segments $PQ$ and $PR$ are 8 inches and 5 inches, respectively, and they make a 60-degree angle at P. Find the length of the angle bisector of angle R.

Through the Law of Sines I was able to find that the angle measure of R is approximately $81.787^{\circ}$ and from the Law of Cosines I figured out that the measure of side $QR$ is 7 inches.

I am unsure of what steps I should take to find the measure of the angle bisector. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean $QR =7$

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say angle bisector cuts $PQ$ at $S$ and let $PS=x$ then $SQ = 8-x$. By angle bisector theorem we have:
 $$ {x\over 8-x} = {5\over 7}$$
and you get $x$. Then use the law of cosinus for triangle $PRS$.

Comment: I got the answer to be $\approx 4.410$ inches.